# How to remove duplicates from the database table, alter the model with unique=True and makemigrations?

Tags: django, django-models

```
class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    class Meta:
        abstract=True
        ordering=['name']
class Student(CommonInfo):
    home_group =models.CharField(max_length=5)
    class Meta(CommonInfo.Meta):
        db_table='student_info'
```

I have a similar database model with existing data. I want to add a uique=True on the field name. Is there any way I could remove the existing duplicate data before I alter the field name as unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the remove duplicates logic in your migration, for example:

Assuming that you have an `ExampleModel` with an `example_field` already migrated and with data, first, you need to include the unique constraint into that field:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    ...
    example_field = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    ...
```

Then make the migration to that model with `makemigrations`, once you have a migration script ready, you can modify it including an additional operation **before** the `AlterField` operation, something like:

```
...

def remove_duplicates(apps, schema_editor):
    ExampleModel = apps.get_model("example_app", "ExampleModel")
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias

    # Get the unique values for the "example_field"
    unique_value_list = ExampleModel.objects.using(db_alias).values_list('example_field', flat=True).distinct()

    for unique_value in unique_value_list:
        # Get ids for a specific value except the first one
        pks = (
            ExampleModel.objects.using(db_alias)
            .filter(example_field=unique_value)
            .values_list('id', flat=True)[1:]
        )

        # Remove selected ids
        ExampleModel.objects.using(db_alias).filter(id__in=pks).delete()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    ...
    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(remove_duplicates), # Include the remove duplicates operation
        migrations.AlterField(
            ...
```

Now, your `migration` should work normally.

This is a very simple example, you might need to do some additional things like lock the table while running the migration to avoid possible errors during the migration, but hope it is clear.

Comment: Can the remove_duplicates and the alteration of the field be on the same migration file? will that not create a problem?

Comment: Yeah, both operations can be in the same file, indeed the migration file is designed to support many operations. But if you want granularity you can put the remove_duplicates operation into a separated migration file, you just need to ensure that the field alteration should depend on the removed duplicates migration. Apart from that, the only missing thing here is the reverse operation for the remove_duplicates but you will need that just if you want to do a rollback of your migration. https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/4.0/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython

Comment: It would really be nice if Django provided this functionality built-in.

Comment: I'm getting an error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: cannot ALTER TABLE "app_model" because it has pending trigger events`

Comment: I see `django.db.utils.OperationalError: cannot ALTER TABLE "app_model" because it has pending trigger events` issue too.